# Jira JQL | Get All tickets to which user has permission

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Admin account is being used, and API to fetch the tickets to get only ticket that user has access to. Eg, we have Jira Account Id (string we get after authentication) now I want to get all issues which this user has access to.
I have also searched and gone through JQL documentation but found nothing.

How this can be achieved with Admin account.

Answer (score -1):

To get all tickets the user has permission to, use this JQL Query:

```
project in projectsWhereUserHasPermission("Work on issues") order by lastViewed DESC
```

You have to use the Jira API and Oauth in order to get the current user. For further reference, please visit [Jira's documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/7.0.0/com/atlassian/jira/security/PermissionManager.html).

Comment: But this will also fetch result in scope of Admin account as its not defining user anywhere.